# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^{\ln n}}$.

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{x^{\ln n}}$$
and I wanna know for what x this series is converge. I think with condensation test if 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\dfrac{1}{x^{n\ln2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\dfrac{2}{x^{\ln2}})^n$$
be converged, then we should have $|\dfrac{2}{x^{\ln2}}|<1$ with geometric series, then for $x>\sqrt[\ln2]{2}$ our series is converge.

Is it correct? I appreciate any suggestion or any other solution?

Comment: This shows the series is diverge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. It can be done without invoking the condensation test.

Notice that $x\geq 0$ otherwise $x^{\ln(n)}$ is not well defined as a real number. $$x^{\ln(n)}=e^{\ln(x)\ln(n)}=n^{\ln(x)}$$
So you must have $\ln(x)>1$ for convergence. So $x>e$.

You may ask $e\stackrel{?}{=} \sqrt[\ln(2)]{2}$? The answer is yes, because:
$$\sqrt[\ln(2)]{2}=2^{1/\ln(2)}=e^{\ln(2)/\ln(2)}=e^1=e$$

Comment: Thanks. Is my reasoning true?

Comment: @maryam Yes your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks again . .